# Sorting ListView by date of items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, sorting, dictionary

I have a `ListView` to show some images (using `ImageList`). Everything works fine so far. I can sort items by theire `Text` property easily. But I want to be able to sort them by theire creation date as well (ASC or DESC).

Items are created like this:

```
Item.Text = file name
item.Tag = file path
```

I am trying to sort the date like this but no success in sorting the dictionary, and also I have no idea how to cast that dictionary items back into listview:

```
private void menuViewSortDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var files = new Dictionary<ListViewItem, DateTime>();

    foreach(ListViewItem item in listViewLoadedImages.Items)
    {
        files.Add(item, File.GetCreationTime(item.Tag.ToString()));
    }

    listViewLoadedImages.BeginUpdate();
    listViewLoadedImages.Items.Clear();

    // how to sort dictionary by DateTime ??
    // like files.Sort(bydate);

    //How can refer to key values (listviewitems) in dictionary
    listViewLoadedImages.Items.AddRange((ListViewItem)files.Keys); 

    listViewLoadedImages.EndUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Avner says a dictionary is not ordered by default however you could use some LINQ to return a IEnumerable by doing:

```
var results = files.OrderBy(x=>x.Value);
```

I'm also not sure how you can make a ListViewItem unique as your key however you could try and cast your dictionary keys

```
var lvItems = files.Keys.Cast<ListViewItem>();
```

Answer (score 1):

A Dictionary is optimized to be quick to retrieve, but that means the internal order is undefined, and specified by the internal implementation.

If you need to have a specific order for keys, use the [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) class, passing it an IComparer, if necessary, to define the sorting order.